# quick charge but slow discharge of a capacitor

Tags: led, capacitor

I'm trying to find a circuit that will quickly charge a capacitor with a load(led) in the circuit but slowly discharge it (keep the led on longer than it took to turn on).  Is this possible?  Does anyone have a circuit that will do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't a set of diodes combined with different value resistors do the trick? One RC combo in the charge direction to allow for fast charging (or even omit the resistor) and another RC combo in the discharge direction to keep the led on.

Comment: R + LED in series from cap+ to cap- . Cap charged via a diode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put two resistors in series with the cap and then put a diode in parallel with one of the resistors.  This will give you a different time constant depending on if current is flowing in to or out of the capacitor - one resistor will be bypassed by the diode in one direction.  Another possibility is to use two resistors in parallel, with each resistor in series with a diode, and the diodes pointing in opposite directions.  This gives completely independent control over the time constant since only one resistor is used at a time.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3YqsF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This may also do what you want, considering you have two distinct current paths:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjeawa.png)</sup>

Comment: not getting this to work.  Any way you can provide a diagram of what it should look like?

Comment: Added some schematics.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about this some more, as long as your source can supply more current than the LED draws, you should get the fast charge, slow discharge characteristic without having to do anything special.